# Ignoring validation of TextBoxes when pressing a specific button

Tags: .net, winforms, validation

I have a Windows Form with `TextBox` controls and a `Button` on it. The `Validating` event of each `TextBox` makes sure that only well formed input can be submitted (duh). The `Button` is a *clear* button that resets the form, clearing the text boxes values, etc. If I have written something illegal in a `TextBox` and then press the *clear* button, the validation of course fires and I get a `MessageBox` telling me this. So I can't use the *Clear* button unless I manually clear the invalid `TextBox`.

I realize that the reason the `Validating` event fires is that the `TextBox` loses focus when I press the *clear* button, but is there a way to ignore validation in this case?

I tried setting the `Form.AutoValidate` to disabled but then I never get any validation, which isn't exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sufficient for you to set the `CausesValidation` property of the clear button to `false`. This way validation is not triggered if you have the text box selected and press the button.

From MSDN entry for [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control causes validation to be performed on any controls that require validation when it receives focus.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my case, for some reason. Validation happens anyway. Maybe it makes a difference that the button is in a panel on it's own while the validating textboxes are in another panel within a tab page within a tab control within it's own panel on the same form as the panel that the button is in. I will experiment.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. From the top of my head I can't really tell you what would work for that specific situation. When I have some free time, I'll try to create a form with that scenario and see what would work.